# PHP ZipArchive not saving

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm creating a PHP automatic downloader for zipped images. However, the downloaded ZIP is empty! Hopefully somebody will know the issue- it's bound to be simple.

Many thanks, Nick.

**PHP**

```
    foreach($_SESSION["photoBasket"] as $id){
       $files[] = array(
               "loc" => "../photos/$id.png",
               "name" => "$id.png"
                );
    }

    $zipname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zip');
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file["loc"],$file["name"]);
          //$zip->addFromString($file["name"],"something here"); WORKS FINE
        }
        $zip->close();

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip');
    readfile($zipname);
    unlink($zipname);
```

Comment: Are you sure all the directories in your zip path exist? PHP Zip doesn't create directories.

Comment: @Flot2011 there's no extra directories- same directory- note 'file.zip' doesn't have any further directories.

Comment: what about filenames then? any special symbols in them?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the actual ZIP- the downloaded ZIP is empty. Please see revised code & comments below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create your file in a writeable folder; also, your filename should be unique so that two people downloading a ZIP at the same time don't overwrite each other. Let PHP work out the specifics of that, using [tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) and [sys_get_temp_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php). And don't forget to remove the temporary file after you've sent it down the wire!

```
$zipname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zip');
...
unlink($zipname);
```

Comment: Understood, thanks. Not creating any issues now, but the zip file doesn't include any files now- any ideas?

Comment: I see you've edited your question. You need to provide the paths to the files, so that ZipArchive can actually find them (that's probably what the error is about).

Comment: I've removed the paths due to a client request. The file links are still okay in the PHP.

If we were to go "on the fly" with this, how would the code change?

Comment: Incidentally, you might be better off using [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) instead of ZipArchive. I use it in a [WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-download-gallery/), because it allows you to specify that you don't want compression -- great for when you're just creating an archive of compressed images.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Do you know if that's built into PHP?

Comment: Re: PclZip, no, you'll need to [download](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/pclzip-downloads) it. It comes with WordPress so that was convenient for me (also ZipArchive isn't installed on every server, another reason for me to use PclZip!)

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly"?

Comment: On the fly, as in I don't want any ZIP files created. PclZip doesn't seem to have any benefits over ZipArchive though, so might stick with ZipArchive.

Comment: No, you need to create a file, then download it, then unlink it. Re: PclZip advantages, recompressing JPEG files takes time, so being able to tell PclZip not to bother means big speed improvements. One guy using my plugin got 1,000+ images in a 700MB archive created in 6 seconds (he tells me).

Comment: Hm, doesn't explain the problems with the empty ZIP folder- any ideas?

Comment: What have you done to ensure that you have the correct full paths to the images? e.g. add some debug code to check [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: Have updated the code, and double-checked that the images exist using `file_exist`. They do, and the ZIP is still empty.

Comment: 1. ZipArchive::open() returns a status; if !== true, report it and check against [status constants](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php)

Comment: 2. are you able to read any image information from the images, e.g. using [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) ?

Comment: 3. [addFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) takes a second parameter, the file's name without path; try adding that in case it doesn't want to add your path in the Zip archive (ps: host Linux / client Windows by chance? see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#89813))

Comment: The images are fine- I can display them on the page. Also, `$zip->addFromString($file["name"],"something here");` inside the foreach adds all files. I'll try 3 now.

Comment: Many thanks for helping. Turns out that one of the photo files was "corrupt" to the ZipArchive- not sure why as it opens/displays fine, `file_exists` works, but removal of that photo allows the code to work.

Comment: I hope that "../photos/$id.png" is an example only; you should be providing the absolute path to the image. e.g. `dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/photos/$id.png"`